# Error in fetch response, can't figure out what is happening: React - Flask - SQLAlchemy

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, sqlalchemy

Thank you to read me at least :)

I'm trying to make a login and register system. It was working before but it breaks at somepoint. I can't figure out what is going on here. My backend is doing his work, generate the token. But when the response comeback to the front again it enter directly in the .catch. I have a headache with this because I don't see nothing wrong...

Could you sir iluminate my way please?

This is my endpoint, it works good.

```
@api.route('/login' , methods=['POST']) 
def login_user():

    body = request.get_json()
    user_check_email = body['email'] 
    user_check_password = body['password']
    
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=user_check_email).first()
    if user is None:
        raise APIException('Usuario no encontrado /routes login l 89')

    # la funcion checkpw usa BYTES no STRINGS por eso hay que hacer enconde !!!!!!!
    passwordCheck = bcrypt.checkpw(user_check_password.encode('utf-8'), user.password.encode('utf-8'))
    print('esto es passwordCheck', passwordCheck)
    if passwordCheck is False:
        raise APIException('Clave incorrecta /routes login l 95')

    data = {
        "id": user.id,
        'email': user.email,
        'nickname': user.nickname,
        'name': user.name,
        'surname': user.surnames
    }

    token = create_access_token(identity=data)
    return jsonify(token), 201
```

Response of this is the token: [image]

My fetch function:

```
login: (email, password) => {
                fetch(`${config.hostname}/api/login`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({email, password}),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log("esto es res", res)
                    if (res.status == 200 || res.status == 201){
                        
                        setStore({nombre: res.nickname})
                        setStore({userVotes: true})
                        
                        setStore({loginEmailPassMatch: false})
                        alert("esto es el res 200")

                    } else {
        
                        setStore({loginEmailPassMatch: true}) 
                        return "Usuario o clave incorrectas"
                    }
                    
                    return res.json()
                })
                .then(data => {
                    console.log("esto es data l 137", data)
                    localStorage.setItem("token", data)
                    setStore({token: data})
                    
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log("esto es error", {error})
                    alert("error en el fetch flux l 147", error)
                })
            },
```

**This is what happens, the response enters directly in .catch:**
[image]

**This is the error:**
[image]

**This is error headers:**
[image]

**Any idea of what is going on here? Thank you!! :D**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the input, I had these attributes that were breaking my code. Why? I don't really know but I commented them and all works fine.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your answer. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set your CORS header on your server

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Also, when using set store, you should always remember to include the previous state using the spread operator:

```js
setStore({nombre: res.nickname, ...store})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `body: JSON.stringify({email, password}),`
to :

```
body: JSON.stringify({
       email: this.state.email,
       password: this.state.password
    }),
```

Comment: I'm afraid that It still doesn't work

Comment: change fetch(`${config.hostname}/api/login`       to           fetch(`${config.hostname}/api/login/`

Comment: I was trying some things and I am thinking that is a CORS problem

Answer (score 0):

I dont know but maybe you are using setStore the wrong way? like i think you have to return old values too. The way i see here you are asigning new values everytime in the setStore. You should return old values too. like setStore({nombre: res.nickname,userVotes:True})